# Image header loading in all browsers but Safari, why?

Tags: wordpress, image, advanced-custom-fields

On my companies website that has just gone live, the header image which is pulled through Advance Custom Fields via WordPress is working fine. The URL string is loading correctly and everything seems good. However when I check it on Safari, it doesn't seem to be loading.

Any ideas?

http://www.wessexlabels.co.uk

Comment: Could you please post a screenshot or be more specific on what image are you thinking, since your logo is displaying to me on Chrome and Safari. (http://imgur.com/a/bszCC)

Comment: Thanks for the help, it turned out to be a syntax error; missing bracket.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your website looks fine for me in Chrome for Windows, Chrome on Mac OSX, Safari on Mac OSX, and Safari on iOS. (latest versions)

It doesn't work properly in Safari 5.1 for Windows however that is an old discontinued browser.

There is a typo in the header that is being ignored by newer browsers, the style element on the header should contain `url(.....)`   but it contains `url(.....`  (i.e. the closing bracket is missing)

when I fix this in the developer tools of Safari 5.1 the background image loads.

```
<section>
  <header class="image-hero" style="background-image: url(http://www.wessexlabels.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2017/07/desk3-min.jpg" alt="Page Image" "173);"="">
    (....)
  </header>
</section>
```

Comment: Thanks so much, definitely was just a syntax error. Clearly overlooked that, so much appreciated!

On a further note, it seems the styling is all over the shot in the version of Safari, what would be the easiest way to fix? Or shouldn't I bother supporting?

Comment: If you are referring specifically to Safari for Windows - users can no longer obtain it directly from the Apple website, so I would consider it discontinued and if your client requires that you will need to rework your layout and styles significantly (e.g. I haven't done a full comparison but you use flex which is also not supported in Safari 5.1 for windows).

Comment: I'll consider the website complete then, as I downloaded the browser through a different source and not Apple. Thanks so much for your help! :D